# NextJS 13 not re-rendering variable after change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, upload

I have an input file that triggers a handleFileEvent function onChange:

```js
<input
  id='file-upload'
  name='file-upload'
  type='file'
  multiple
  accept='application/pdf, image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg'
  className='sr-only'
  onChange={handleFileEvent}
/>
```

My handleFileEvent has the following code:

```js
const handleFileEvent = async (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  if (event.target.files) {
    setFileList(event.target.files);
  }
};
```

The problem is: my fileList variable is always null.

```js
const [fileList, setFileList] = useState<FileList | null>(null);
```

I added an useEffect hook to detect the variable change and it's triggering:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('useEffect fileList', fileList);
}, [fileList]);
```

But when I try to use this value to render the preview of the file, the `fileList` always has the null value.

Any idea why after `setFileList` Next is not rerendering the component?

Im using React Hook Form on this form. Trying to check out if this retaled to how it handles input fields.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the scenario I tried in both a virtual environment and also local NextJS 13 environment. In each scenario, the FileList changes with the change in input. Sorry that I couldn't help. Can you provide some more information or reproduction in something like stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: Hi @PHSaurav. I found the problem. My `input` was located inside the tag `label`. Thanks for helping.